# Get system property "java.class.path" from adb shell

Tags: android, adb, android-source

Does anybody know how to read system property "java.class.path" using adb shell in Android?

**Edit:** `adb shell getprop java.class.path` returns nothing.

Comment: It seems from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html that java.class.path is equal to . But I'm not sure so I leave this question open for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this answer is the right one. From the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html it can be inferred that `"java.class.path"` property is equal to `"."`

Answer (score 0):

Use the command "adb shell getprop", to view all available properties and values list.